# How to create a TableView without a deletion control?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

When a table view goes into editing mode, it shows the delete controls on the left, and also reordering controls on the right.

I have no need for deleting the rows, hence I return `UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone` for `-(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`.

But doing so merely hides the red delete control. The table row will still be indented when I go into editing mode. Is it possible to hide the deletion control completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to also return NO for [– tableView:shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007125).